# Atomic std::shared_ptrs before c++20

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr, atomic

Currently I'm using task based scheduling to ensure "thread safe" shared ptr setting/getting, but that is insanely inefficient.

How would one implement atomic shared ptrs using C++11?  Can we just use the std::atomic> template?

Comment: `atomic_store/load` overloads for `shared_ptr` exist since C++11. Check [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic)

Comment: awesome, thx ___